# Find the volume of bullet shape solid.

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative, polar-coordinates

Bullet function is given by $y = 16 - x^2 - z^2$ to the right of the $xz-$plane.

I have set up the following integral but not sure whether it is true or not. 
$\int_{-4}^{4} \int_{0}^{2π} \int_{0}^{4} (16-r^2) r dr d \theta dz$.

Comment: You converted to polar coordinates, correct? It seems you used $r^2=x^2+z^2$, and I doubt you need the $z$ integral at all.

Comment: put the '$' around the Math functions

Comment: I thought I have to use cylindrical coordinates as bullet function is given. So I converted this function to cylindrical coordinates. (x,y,z,) -> (r, $\theta$ , z)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is $y = 16 - x^2 - z^2$, so think about apply cylindrical coordinates in the way that $r^2 = x^2 + z^2$. And since you are trying to find the volume, shouldn't your integrand be $1*Jacobian$?

Comment: yes, i did use cylindrical coordinates. But what did you mean by $1 * Jacobian$ ? I came up with this integral. $\int_{-4}^{4} \int_{0}^{2π} \int_{0}^{4} (16-r^2) r dr d \theta dz$ But not sure whether it is right or not.

Comment: Since you have $y = 16 - x^2 - z^2$, so it is $y = 16 - r^2$. So your integral should be $\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^4\int_0^{16-r^2}(1*r)d_\theta d_rd_y$, where $r$ is the Jacobian term for cylindrical coordinates.

Comment: Actually $\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^4\int_0^{16-r^2}(1*r)d_yd_rd_\theta$.

Comment: Oh yes. Since we are dealing with $x^2 + z^2 = r^2$, we have to take $dy$. But Isn't $1 * Jacobian $ use to find area? For volume, it is $\rho(r,\theta,y) * Jacobian$ . Right?

Comment: I guess by $\rho(r, \theta,y)$, you mean the density function. If we are looking for the mass, which is $volume * density$, yeah, we need the density function $\rho$. But since our target is the volume, it is still $1 * Jacobian$. Actually you could think "volume" as "area" in 3d space.

Comment: make sense. Thanks Xuan